# C# Console Progressbar

Tags: c#, console, progress

Hello so i needed to have progress bar in C# console application when downloading files from FTP, but it was little bit too dificult for me so i used already done API and libraries.

Im using FluentFTP: https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP#faq_progress
And progressbar console function from: https://gist.github.com/co89757/5ae15bf61a62f82f9abd32a285f0c76a

Ive done something like this:

```
        //Download files from FTP, return true or false if succed
        public static void DownloadFileFromFTP(string ip, string RemoteFilePath, string LocalFilePath, string username, string password)
        {

             FtpClient client = new FtpClient(ip);
             client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
             client.Connect();

            using (var progress = new ProgressBar())
            {

                   client.DownloadFile(LocalFilePath, RemoteFilePath, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, progress);

            }

        }
```

No problem with function at all works as expected. Problem is with progressbar which just turn 100% very fast i didnt download like maybe 5% of file and progressbar shows 100%.

Did i get any documentation wrong or can someone help where is the problem?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Are you sure you want to download the same file 101-times?

Comment: Sry old code, i edited. But it does same thing without for cycle.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is iterating over a for loop 100 times, and downloading it that exact amount of times. What you have to do is create a progress bar set the minimun to 0 and the maximun to 100. Then you need to define a callback function that updates your progress whenever its called (according to the documentation this is done by the function provided)

To keep it short, you need to add the following (copied from the documentation you linked)

and your method should look like this

```
        //Download files from FTP, return true or false if succed
    public static void DownloadFileFromFTP(string ip, string RemoteFilePath, string LocalFilePath, string username, string password)
    {
         ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

         Progress<double> progress = new Progress<double>(x => {
           if (x > 0)
           {
             progressBar.Report((double) x / 100);
           }   
         });
         FtpClient client = new FtpClient(ip);
         client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
         client.Connect();
         progressBar = new ProgressBar();
         client.DownloadFile(LocalFilePath, RemoteFilePath, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, progress);
         progressBar.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah i knew i just copied old code edited with deleted for cycle. But this i found but i thought its only for windows form, cause i dont know "progressBar" is i thought its created object in windows form and i need this in console. And the function i post dont have functions like IsInDeterminate, Value and so on

Comment: still saying use of unassigned local variable 'progressBar' in
```
Progress<double> progress = new Progress<double>(x => {
                    if (x > 0)
                    {
                        progressBar.Report((double)x / 100);
                    }
                });```

Comment: okay then try instantiating the progress bar in the first line then ProgressBar progressBar should change to ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();